# How to measure the memory usage of a Mongodb aggregation?

Tags: performance, mongodb, memory, query-performance

I recently started running into the `Sort exceeded memory limit of...` exception on an aggregation pipeline in MongoDB. I got around this by setting `AllowDiskUse=True` for the aggregation. However, I read that this can significantly slow down performance.

I would like to optimize the query but I cannot figure out how to measure how much memory is being used by the aggregation. 
I also need to run the pipeline on multiple collections in production so I need to know how the memory usage will scale with collection-size.

Does anyone know how to do this? The .explain() method does not seem to show any information on memory usage and I haven't found anything in the docs/forums.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726028/increasing-memory-limit-for-mongodb-aggregate-jobs) one and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255816/what-can-be-done-with-mongo-aggregation-performance-of-mongo-aggregation) one too.